# Validate attribute only if it present (only if user fill in it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I need validate some attributes ONLY if they are not empty.

For example the user may have a logo. If we try to load it - validation should work. If we simply update the user's data without the logo, validation must be skipped.

Now i have:

The form has a choice of two files. One - logo, second - avatar.
Both of this attributes is part of User model. In User model a have validation:

```
validates_preference_of :logo_file_name, :message=>I18n.t("...")
validates_format_of :logo_file_name, :with=>/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i, :message=> I18n.t("...")
validates_preference_of :avatar_file_name, :message=>I18n.t("...")
validates_format_of :avatar_file_name, :with=>/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i, :message=> I18n.t("...")
```

In this case, if we try to create a new User without selected logo and avatar, we will have errors (our validation). I tryed change validation and add ":on => :update" like this:

```
validates_preference_of :logo_file_name, :message=>I18n.t("..."), :on => :update
validates_format_of :logo_file_name, :with=>/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i, :message=> I18n.t("..."), :on => :update
validates_preference_of :avatar_file_name, :message=>I18n.t("..."), :on => :update
validates_format_of :avatar_file_name, :with=>/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i, :message=> I18n.t("..."), :on => :update
```

Now i can create user without selected logo and avatar, but if i try edit user and try upload only logo - i have validation errors of avatar. If i choose file for avatar and logo leave blank - i have validation errors for logo.

How i can run validation ony for attribute that I want to change?

Comment: What's validates_preference_of? Do you mean validates_presence_of?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Add `:allow_blank => true` and it should do what you want.

Comment: Just to add, if you're running into this problem and you need to set this `:allow_blank => true` on multiple attributes it may be a sign that you need to separate those attributes into a new model and make a 1 to 1 relationship to the original model. That way you can create a separate validation that will have these attributes required.

Comment: Note if you have multiple validations on the same field, they each have to have `:allow_blank => true`

Answer (score 12):

Maybe `:if => lambda {|attr| attr.present?}` will help?

Comment: I like this because it works everywhere and you don't have to guess which methods support the other solution.

Answer (score 12):

Some validations accept the options `:allow_blank => true` or  `:allow_nil => true`.

If this fails, use :if condition, like this:

```
validates_format_of :avatar_file_name, 
 :with=>/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i, 
 :message=> I18n.t("..."), 
 :on => :update,
 :if => lambda{ |object| object.avatar_file_name.present? }
```

But i encourage you to use allows. Much cleaner.